# How to average multiindex row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The objective is to average the first level of a multi index row.

For example, the task it to average the rows (s1,s2) and (s1,s3).

Given the following `df`

```
          a  fe  gg new_text
(s1, s2)  4   0   3        t
(s1, s3)  3   3   1        t
(s2, s3)  3   2   4        t
(s2, s4)  0   0   4        t
(s3, s1)  2   1   0        t
(s3, s4)  1   1   0        t
```

The expected output is as below

```
    a  fe  gg new_text
s1  7   3   4 t      
s2  3   2   8 t      
s3  3   3   0 t
```

I tried using the following syntax

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean'])
```

Which produced undersired output

```
            a   fe   gg
         mean mean mean
(s1, s2)  4.0  0.0  3.0
(s1, s3)  3.0  3.0  1.0
(s2, s3)  3.0  2.0  4.0
(s2, s4)  0.0  0.0  4.0
(s3, s1)  2.0  1.0  0.0
(s3, s4)  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

May I know how to address this problem.

The output can be reproduced using the following codes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

arr=np.random.randint(5, size=(6, 3))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, index=[('s1','s2'),('s1','s3'),('s2','s3'),('s2','s4'),('s3','s1'),('s3','s4')],
                  columns=['a','fe','gg'])
df['new_text']='t'
df2=df.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index.tolist())
df.groupby(level=0).agg({'a': 'sum', 'fe': 'sum', 'gg': 'sum', 'new_text': 'first'})
```

produces

```
    a  fe  gg new_text
s1  7   3   4 t      
s2  3   2   8 t      
s3  3   3   0 t
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `sum` and not `mean`.

```
agg_dict = {'a':'sum', 'fe':'sum', 'gg':'sum', 'new_text':'first'}
out = df.groupby([m[0] for m in df.index]).agg(agg_dict)
print(out)

    a  fe  gg new_text
s                     
s1  7   3   4        t
s2  3   2   8        t
s3  3   2   0        t
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used tuples as the entries in the index for your DataFrame, but you haven't used a `MultiIndex`.

If you use a MultiIndex, you can use `xs()` to select the subset of entries you want to calculate the mean:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[c[0] for c in df.index], [c[1] for c in df.index]])
```

With the index converted to a MultiIndex, the DataFrame now prints like so:

```
       a  fe  gg
s1 s2  4   1   4
   s3  1   1   1
s2 s3  4   2   3
   s4  2   2   4
s3 s1  1   4   3
   s4  2   3   1
```

Now we can pick out the rows we want to use for the calculation with `xs()`, in this case all rows with 's1' in the 0th level of the MultiIndex:

```
df.xs('s1').mean(axis=0)
```

Result:

```
a     2.5
fe    1.0
gg    2.5
dtype: float64
```

You can also use `groupby` as you had expected, now that you have a proper MultiIndex:

```
df.groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Result:

```
      a   fe   gg
s1  2.5  1.0  2.5
s2  3.0  2.0  3.5
s3  1.5  3.5  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

i Hope that help

```
a=df.index.values.tolist() #get value index 
l=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    l.append(str(a[i]).split("'")[1])

df['new_id']=l
df.groupby("new_id")['a','fe','gg'].sum()
```